# SQL query Frequency Distribution matrix for product

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, hiveql

i want to create a frequency distribution matrix

```
1.Create a matrix.**Is it possible to get this in separate columns**

  customer1       p1         p2      p3
  customer 2      p2         p3
  customer 3      p2         p3      p1
  customer 4      p2         p1

2. Then I have to count the number of products that come together the most

   For eg  
    p2 and p3 comes together 3 times
    p1 p3   comes 2 times
    p1 p2  comes  2 times

I want to recommend products to customers ,frequency of products that comes together

 select customerId,product,count(*) from sales group by customerId,product
```

Can anyone please help me for a solution to this

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: As for you last edit - Only if you determine in advance the maximum number of products per customer

Comment: yes i have the data

Comment: What is the bounty for? separate columns? SQL query **always** has a defined number of columns at parsing time.The only way to achieve a "dynamic" number of a records is to execute a query that returns the max number of products per customer and than generate another query, similar to the query in my answer, with the now known number of columns.

Comment: You got some nice questions ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want pairs of products that customers purchase, then you can use a self join:

```
select s1.product, s2.product, count(*) as cnt
from sales s1 join
     sales s2
     on s1.customerId = s2.customerId
where s1.product < s2.product
group by s1.product, s2.product
order by cnt desc;
```

You can extend this to more than two products by using more joins.

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

**Array**

```
select      customerId
           ,sort_array(collect_set (product))   as products

from        sales 

group by    customerId
;
```

**Multiple columns**

```
select      customerId

           ,products[0] as p0
           ,products[1] as p1
           ,products[2] as p2
           ,products[3] as p3
           ,products[4] as p4
           ,products[5] as p5
           ,products[6] as p6
           ,products[7] as p7
           ,products[8] as p8
           ,products[9] as p9

from       (select      customerId
                       ,sort_array(collect_set (product))   as products

            from        sales 

            group by    customerId
            ) s
;
```

**2.**

This returns the frequency of the whole products' combinations.
In your example `(p1,p2,p3)` is the most frequent (appears twice).
`(p1,p2)` appears once and so is `(p2,p3)`.
For frequency of tuples, see @GordonLinoff answer.

```
select      s.products
           ,count(*)    as frequency 

from       (select      customerId
                       ,sort_array(collect_set (product))   as products

            from        sales 

            group by    customerId
            ) s

group by    s.products           

order by    frequency desc
```

Comment: can you please explain the second query

Comment: I am not getting the desired result with second query

Comment: Check @GordonLinoff answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff not working .it gives error message SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'product'

Comment: He forgot to group by `s1.product, s2.product`

Comment: s1.product < s2.product what does this indicate

Comment: Dudu,query number 1 is working fine .exactly what I want but query 2 doesnt give the distribution properly

Comment: Your example is wrong. P2+P3 repeats 2 times, not 3.

Comment: s1.product < s2.product means??

Comment: If you'll remove it  you'll get all tuples combinations, including a product with itself, e.g. `(p2,p2)`. If you'll use `s1.product <> s2.product` you'll get any combination twice in an opposite order e.g. `(p2,p3)` and `(p3,p2)`. By using s1.product < s2.product you'll get only `(p2,p3)` (`p2` is alphabetically "smaller" than `p3`)

Comment: ,Query number 2 gives what i need ["Butter","Leather shoes","Poptarts","T short"] 3
It is possible to make these into separate columns rather than a array,so i can i can further drill down to get the possible combinations

Answer (score 1):

I know cursors are not the *flavor of the month* anymore - but I still find them very useful from time to time

Below code creates a table variable and then loops through the **sales data** to find out which *combination of products* are sold together most frequently

```
--Results will be loaded into this table
DECLARE @OutputCombination TABLE (CombinationName VARCHAR(MAX), CombinationsFound INT) 

--Just for demo - create table and load with data
declare @demodata table (ClientID int, ProductBought varchar(50))
insert into @demodata (Clientid, ProductBought) values 
(1,'Coke'),
(1,'Chips'),
(1,'Chips'),
(2,'Coke'),
(2,'Coke'),
(2,'Sweets'),
(3,'Coke'),
(4,'Chips'),
(5,'Coke'),
(5,'Chips'),
(6,'Coke'),
(7,'Coke')

DECLARE clients CURSOR
READ_ONLY
FOR SELECT DISTINCT clientID from @demodata

DECLARE @clientID INT
OPEN clients

FETCH NEXT FROM clients INTO @clientID
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
       DECLARE @ThisClientCombination VARCHAR(MAX) --This is going to be used to find/update combinations of products sold from the data - pipe-delimiting them
       SET @ThisClientCombination  = '' --better to actually wipe variables in cursor loops, as cursors sometimes funny about things like that
       ;WITH thisClientsDistinctCoverages AS --CTE used because of the SQL-funnies caused when using DISTINCT and ORDER BY
       (
              SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT CoverageItems = ProductBought + '|' FROM @demodata WHERE ClientID = @clientID ORDER BY ProductBought + '|' --order alphabetically and do DISTINCT so that 2x cokes are changed into just 1 coke - for the sake of combos
       )
       SELECT @ThisClientCombination = @ThisClientCombination + CoverageItems FROM thisClientsDistinctCoverages
       SET @ThisClientCombination = LEFT(@ThisClientCombination,LEN(@ThisClientCombination)-1) --Drop trailing Pipe '|'

       IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @OutputCombination WHERE CombinationName = @ThisClientCombination)
              UPDATE @OutputCombination SET CombinationsFound = CombinationsFound + 1 WHERE CombinationName = @ThisClientCombination --found before, increase count by 1
       ELSE
              INSERT INTO @OutputCombination (CombinationName, CombinationsFound) VALUES (@ThisClientCombination, 1)--first time found, make entry 1

       FETCH NEXT FROM clients INTO @clientID
END

CLOSE clients
DEALLOCATE clients

--Show the results
SELECT * FROM @OutputCombination ORDER BY CombinationsFound DESC, CombinationName
```

**This will yield the results:**

> CombinationName---------CombinationsFound
>   Coke--------------------------3
>   Chips|Coke------------------2
>   Chips--------------------------1
>   Coke|Sweets----------------1

**Interpretation of above results:** 
Most often, **3 times**, a customer only bought coke(s) 
Next up, **twice** a customer bought chips and a coke
**Once** a customer only bought chips
And **once** a customer bought a coke & sweets