# Frequency of all combinations of values for certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset in SQL Server 2012 with a column for id and value, like this:

```
[id]  [value]
--------------
A        15
A        11
A        11
B        13
B        15
B        12
C        12
C        13
D        13  
D        12
```

My goal is to get a frequency count of all combinations of [value], with two caveats:

1. Order doesn't matter, so [11,12,15] is not counted separately from [12,11,15]
2. Repeated values are counted separately, so [11,11,12,15] is counted separately from [11,12,15]
3. I'm interested in all combinations, of any length (not just pairs)

So the outcome would look like:

```
[combo]   [frequency]
---------------------
11,11,15  1
12,13,15  1
12,13     2
```

I've seen answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653329/sql-query-to-find-all-combinations-in-a-shopping-cart-and-their-occurrence) involving recursion that answer similar questions but where order counts, and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749016/sql-query-frequency-distribution-matrix-for-product) involving self-joins that yield pair-wise combinations. These come close but I'm not quite sure how to adapt for my specific needs.

Comment: tag your sql engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg()`:

```
select vals, count(*) as frequency
from (select string_agg(value, ',') within group (order by value) as vals, id
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by vals;
```

SQL Server 2012 doesn't support `string_agg()` but you can use the XML hack:

```
select vals, count(*) as frequency
from (select id,
             stuff( (select concat(',', value)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = i.id
                     for xml path ('')
                    ), 1, 1, ''
                  ) as vals
      from (select distinct id from t) i
     ) i
group by vals;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number string is just all the values with the same `id` in increasing order. So I'm treating the lowest `id` as a canonical name for the full sequence and all its matches. This spares all the string manipulations though you can expand as necessary.

Just tag each duplicate value with a counter and then look for groups that pair up completely.

```
with data as (
    select id, value,
        row_number() over (partition by id, value) as rn
), matches as (
    select l.id, r.id as match
    from data l full outer join data r on
         l.value = r.value and l.rn = r.rn and l.id <= r.id
    group by l.id
    having count(l.id) = count(*) and count(r.id) = count(*)
)
select id, count(match) as frequency
from matches
group by id;
```

The logic in the middle query is also easily adaptable for finding subset of values in common.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CTEs and row_number functions.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(id CHAR(1), val int)

insert into @table VALUES
('A',15),
('A',11),
('A',11),
('B',13),
('B',15),
('B',12),
('C',12),
('C',13),
('D',13),  
('D',12);

;WITH CTE_rnk as
(
SELECT id,val, row_number() over (partition by id order by val) as rnk
from @table
),
CTE_concat as
(
SELECT id, cast(val as varchar(100)) as val, rnk
from CTE_rnk 
where rnk =1
union all
SELECT r.id, cast(concat(c.val,',',r.val) as varchar(100)) as val,r.rnk 
from CTE_rnk as r
inner join CTE_concat as c
on r.rnk = c.rnk+1
and r.id = c.id
),
CTE_maxcombo as
(
SELECT id,val, row_number() over(partition by id order by rnk desc) as rnk
from CTE_concat
)
select val as combo, count(*) as frequency 
from CTE_maxcombo where rnk = 1
group by val
```

```
+----------+-----------+
|  combo   | frequency |
+----------+-----------+
| 11,11,15 |         1 |
|    12,13 |         2 |
| 12,13,15 |         1 |
+----------+-----------+
```