# Partial Combination Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Another person asked a similar question found here:
[Frequency of all combinations of values for certain column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62544806/20402106)

in it they asked:

*I have a dataset in SQL Server 2012 with a column for id and value, like this:

```
[id]  [value]
--------------
A        15
A        11
A        11
B        13
B        15
B        12
C        12
C        13
D        13  
D        12
```

My goal is to get a frequency count of all combinations of [value], with two caveats:

Order doesn't matter, so [11,12,15] is not counted separately from [12,11,15]

Repeated values are counted separately, so [11,11,12,15] is counted separately from [11,12,15]

I'm interested in all combinations, of any length (not just pairs)

So the outcome would look like:

```
[combo]   [frequency]
---------------------
11,11,15  1
12,13,15  1
12,13     2
```

I've seen answers here involving recursion that answer similar questions but where order counts, and answers here involving self-joins that yield pair-wise combinations. These come close but I'm not quite sure how to adapt for my specific needs.*

somone then responded with a pretty good response/answer

```
select vals, count(*) as frequency
from (select string_agg(value, ',') within group (order by value) as vals, id
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by vals;
```

The only problem I see is although 12,13,15 occurs once and 12,13,(nothing) happens twice the solution I would like is that 12,13 actually occurs 3 times (while also reporting 12,13,15 count as well)!

@Gordon Linoff
@zealous

```
select vals, count(*) as frequency
from (select string_agg(value, ',') within group (order by value) as vals, id
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by vals;
```

expecting counts of any instance of two or more values in a combination.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an overlapping groups problem here, i.e (12,13) overlaps with (12,13,15) and (11,12,13). You may solve this problem by performing a self left join as the following query.

Note that your version of *(SQL Server 2012)* does not support the `STRING_AGG` function so I used the `xml path` method instead.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT T.id
   , STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',', D.[value]) 
          FROM table_name D
          WHERE D.id = T.id
          ORDER BY D.[value]
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS combo
  FROM table_name T
  GROUP BY T.id
)

SELECT A.combo, COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) frequency
FROM CTE A LEFT JOIN CTE B
ON B.combo LIKE CONCAT('%', A.combo, '%')
GROUP BY A.combo
ORDER BY MAX(A.id)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_NG-AjQH).

The output according to your input data:

```
combo       frequency
11,11,15    1
12,13,15    1
12,13       3
```